# Как избежать слишком частого повторного рендера RecyclerView при использовании Flowable (RxJava)?

Tags: android, rxjava, android-room

Реализую MVVM с room + flowable из rxjava + retrofit2.

При открытии активити из репозитория мне прилетает FLowable со списком элементов из БД (room).
В этот же момент репозиторий запрашивает список у API, как только возвращается результат я удаляю имеющиеся записи в бд и вставляю то что прилетело от API.

Наблюдатель в активити разумеется успевает аж три раза отрендерить список в recyclerview. При этом заметно моргание: список не пустой -> список пустой -> список не пустой.

Получив один раз flowable из room'a со списком элементов, обсервер получает потом и пустой список (при удалении записей в БД) и затем новый список после вставки в БД.

Как избежать в этом случае слишком частого повторного рендера RecyclerView?
Есть какая-то устоявшаяся бэст-практис, тру вэй и т. п.?

Comment: Сделайте удаление и вставку в бд одной транзакцией, плюс можно прикрепить DiffUtil

Comment: Использовать транзакцию для удаления и добавление данных в БД. Использовать заглушку на время подгрузки данных из сети. Ну и зачем собственно постоянно удалять данные? Нельзя просто обновить нужные поля и добавить новые элементы?

Comment: С транзакциями и diffutil понял, спасибо.
Заглушку нет смысла показывать, какая разница что моргает - список или заглушка)